# error: no suitable method found for show(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,String)

Tags: android

I get this error for build java code in Android Studio:

> error: no suitable method found for show(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,String)

I am new to Android Studio and java,but i tried as much i can also did google,but i couldn't

```
selectCarTypeFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "SelectCarTypeFragment");

selectCarTypeFragment.setTargetFragment(selectCarTypeFragment.getTargetFragment(), SELECT_CAR_TYPE_REQUEST_CODE);
selectCarTypeFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "SelectCarTypeFragment");
```

and this import

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit: your `selectCarTypeFragment` doesn't have a `show` method. For us to be able to help better, ensure that you show the [minimal-but-complete code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, how is `selectCarTypeFragment` declared and initialized?

Comment: If I'm allowed to post the project here. This is link project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TkdOxulYyAyirrVVYVcCGWPmCtNRLUTq/view?usp=sharing If not, please tell me to delete the comment. Thank you alot